# Difference in methods of defining two variables at the same time in python

Tags: python, variables

I noticed that in python you can do two things to do a double assignment:

```py
hey,bye = (1,2)

#or

(hey,bye)=(1,2)
```

Is there any real difference between the two?

Comment: Nope, generally it's the commas that make a tuple

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's not a tuple in any sense, is it? I mean, this doesn't create a `tuple` object and also [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt) talks about "target *lists*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those are grouping parentheses, which don't have an effect on how that statement works. You can check they bytecode generated by each and it's exactly the same:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("hey,bye = (1,2)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (hey)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (bye)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("(hey,bye) = (1,2)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (hey)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (bye)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note, the parentheses can matter, if you have nested data:

```
>>> data = [1,2, [3, 4]]
>>> x, y, (z, w) = data
>>> x,y,z,y
(1, 2, 3, 2)
>>> x, y, z, w  = data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

So note the difference in this bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis("x, y, (z, w) = data")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (data)
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (y)
              8 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             10 STORE_NAME               3 (z)
             12 STORE_NAME               4 (w)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("x, y, z, w = data")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (data)
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (y)
              8 STORE_NAME               3 (z)
             10 STORE_NAME               4 (w)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```